# Не устанавливается значение AtomicInteger

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Хочу задать действия для массива кнопок через switch/case, но по сколько через лямбду при выборе кнопки нельзя задать значение для int переменной, чтоб потом обратиться к массиву. Поэтому устанавливаю через AtomicInteger, код ниже.

Установка числа:

```
AtomicInteger e = new AtomicInteger(0);

            button_1.setOnClickListener(view -> e.set(0));
            button_2.setOnClickListener(view -> e.set(1));
```

Действие через switch/case

```
switch(views.get(e.get())){
                case(R.id.button_1):{
                    // действие
                    break;
                }
                case(R.id.button_2):{
                    //действие
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Ну и массив кнопок, если это поможет

```
ArrayList<Integer> views = new ArrayList<>();
        views.add(R.id.button_1);
        views.add(R.id.button_2);
```

Изначально, как и нужно выбрана первая кнопка, но когда нажимаю на вторую, выбрана всё ещё первая. Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Что за switch, где он находится? Почему нельзя действие сразу в лямде выполнять?

Answer (score 0):

Создай отдельный экземпляр `AtomicInteger` для каждой кнопки и добавь его в массив `views` вместе с ID кнопки.

```
ArrayList<Integer> views = new ArrayList<>();
AtomicInteger e1 = new AtomicInteger(0);
AtomicInteger e2 = new AtomicInteger(1);

views.add(R.id.button_1);
views.add(e1);
views.add(R.id.button_2);
views.add(e2);

button_1.setOnClickListener(view -> e1.set(0));
button_2.setOnClickListener(view -> e2.set(1));
```

через  `switch/case`:

```
switch(views.get(e1.get())){
                case(R.id.button_1):{
                    // действие
                    break;
                }
                case(R.id.button_2):{
                    //действие
                    break;
                }
            }
```

или так

```
switch(views.get(e2.get())){
                case(R.id.button_1):{
                    // действие
                    break;
                }
                case(R.id.button_2
```